# iOS - viewDidAppear: delayed when showing a UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, viewdidappear

I'm having a weird problem. I have a Tab Bar application, in it I'm using a Navigation Controller for each of the different tabs and each Navigation Controller has it's own View Controller to display some content.

When I touch a tab I want the tab to be loaded immediately with the view and after it has been loaded (`viewDidAppear:`) I want it to download some data in the viewDidAppear: method.

To test this functionality I have setup the following method. I'm using a `NSThread` to simulate doing some lengthy operation that should be done in the background while the view has been loaded. Then I assign the NSArray *test (nonatomic, retain) with some test data and reload the table.

I'm reloading the table because in the `viewDidLoad` method I'm setting the table to contain only one empty string (this is because I read that the table is setup before viewDidAppear: is called.

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    DLog(@"viewDidAppear running");

    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:10];

    NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Test1", @"Test2", @"Test3", @"Test4", @"Test5", @"Test6", nil];
    self.test = array;

    [array release];

    [table reloadData];
}
```

So my expected behaviour should be that when touching this particular tab it should load **instantly** and then after 10 seconds it should be populated with table data from the viewDidAppear: method. **But** the behaviour is instead that when touching this tab it **waits for 10 seconds** and then it displays the view with the table data populated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:10];` will prevent the main thread from doing any updates so you cannot see any user interface changes. If you want to delay reloading of table data as above, check `NSObject performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` [NSObject Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Put the code for reloadData and array setup in a method an call it via `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:`

Comment: I think that was what I was looking for, but do you perhaps know why the my table isn't showed before viewDidAppear:? My table is waiting is waiting for viewDidAppear: method to run and then shows the table.

Comment: if you "block" code execution in viewDidAppear the user interface will simply not be able to draw and refresh itself as ui refreshing is (mostly) done by that main thread. So after the method is run, the system will run code to actually draw the user interface and your table. Does this help?

Comment: If I remove the NSThread call viewDidAppear will still be delayed. As to my understanding the view should be displayed immediately after loadView has been run and then execute whatever is in viewDidAppear. But the case here is that the view is NOT displayed immediately, it insteads WAIT for viewDidAppear method to run and THEN displays the view.

Comment: What happens within your code after `loadView` and before `viewDidAppear`? Are you e.g. doing some long running setup or use special animation? Normally ' viewDidAppear'  should occur quit quickly after the view was activated (and loaded/created before). Something must cause the time-lap before `viewDidAppear` is called.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers explain why your main thread is blocked when you use `+[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:]` method.

To handle downloading off the web, you should push your downloading task to a background thread so as to avoid blocking the main thread like you have done here. You can achieve this using **Grand Central Dispatch**.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, NULL), ^{
    /* Download stuff */

   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
       /* Send UI updates back to the main thread. */
       [self.tableView reloadData];
   });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, do you by any chance the answer to my question in reply to @marcus?

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you putting the wrong thread to sleep? (Namely the one that will create the array)

Seems you wait 10 seconds and then call the table reloadData.

Why are you waiting anyway? Don't you want the tableView to be filled as soon as the data is available?

Comment: I'm just using NSThread to simulate a lengthy operation. Instead of using NSThread I could be downloading the data from the internet.

Answer (score 0):

```
    -(void)executeMe{


        NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Test1", @"Test2", @"Test3", @"Test4", @"Test5", @"Test6", nil];
        self.test = array;

        [array release];



        [table reloadData];



    }







    - (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {

        [super viewDidAppear:animated];

        DLog(@"viewDidAppear running");



        [self performSelector:@selector(executeMe) withObject:nil afterDelay:10];


    }
```